# I cant figure out how to use two router outlets in angular

Tags: angular

It has been my dream, ever since I started prigramming to build a website. I have finally began working on it and decided to use angular. I'm very new to angular. I'm trying to add a layout with a sidebar, header, footer, and the main content. There is going to be a main base page and other sub domains branching off the problem is I want the design of the elements like the sidebar and the header to stay the same but change the content for each site. I will greatly appreciate any help.
I tried to see if any on the files were dissconnected like not imported, but I couldn't find anything. what I'm wanting to happen is when you click the link go to the /games url it will change the sidebar and the main content.

Here is the code:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, HeaderComponent, SidebarComponent, FooterComponent, RouterModule, RouterLink],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'skerb-network';
}
```

app.routes.ts

```
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { GamesHomeComponent } from './games-home/games-home.component';
import { SidebarGamesComponent } from './sidebar-games/sidebar-games.component';

const routeConfig: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: SidebarComponent,
    outlet: 'sidebar'
  },
  {
    path: 'games',
    component: GamesHomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'games',
    component: SidebarGamesComponent,
    outlet: 'sidebar'
  }
];

export default routeConfig;
```

If you need any other files please let me know!!

and let me know if you need all the files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2 router in appcomponent, one with name attribute

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>  
<router-outlet  name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
```

then for navigate in your named `router-outlet` you can use the navigate with outlets property.

```
this.router.navigate(['game']); // no named router-outelt
this.router.navigate(['', { outlets: { sidebar: 'sidebarGames' } }]); // named router-outelt
```

you can change the router to this

```
const routeConfig: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'sidebarHome',
    component: SidebarComponent,
    outlet: 'sidebar'
  },
  {
    path: 'games',
    component: GamesHomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'sidebarGames',
    component: SidebarGamesComponent,
    outlet: 'sidebar'
  }
];
```

Comment: in my html I have two router outlets one with the named attribute like you showed but can you explain the last part in a little more depth?

Comment: oh I see what happened i wanted there to instead of two different URLs for each side bar, I want it to switch between each sidebar at the same time it changes the main page content

Comment: but can you still explain the part when you use the "navigate with outlets"

Comment: And to be more clear I want the sidebar and the content to change at the same time for the different times.